# How context bind on click in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this

How context bind on click in vue?

Html with click function:

```
<li v-on:click="itemClick($event, this)"></li>
```

My vue js code:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#mainApp',
    methods: {
        itemClick: (event, context) => {
            context.someFunction(); // undefined
            this.someFunction(); // undefined
        }, 
        someFunction: function() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you're using ```options api``` or ```composition api``` ? we need more explanation here

Comment: @cantdocpp, i don`t know. But I change question

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#calling-methods-in-inline-handlers

Comment: I using options api

Comment: in ```options api``` you can just call other method like your example using ```this.someFunction()```

Comment: you can checkout [this pen](https://codepen.io/docker-container/pen/bGObrjr?editors=1111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Event Handling](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#listening-to-events) - Vue Docs

By default, left-click triggers the `@click` event, and right-click triggers the `@contextmenu` event, so similar to native JavaScript, you only need to declare the function to be executed when the event occurs.

- [`methods()`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#methods) - Vue Docs

In the `methods` section, you declare functions within an object, so you just need to use commas between the functions instead of semicolons. Also, follow the pattern I demonstrated for the functions, but you can refer to the example in the attached documentation as well.

The example code you showed follows the structure of the Options API based on its appearance. Therefore, I will provide the example code in my response accordingly.

##### Example with Options API

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <li @click="(event) => itemClick(event)">Test</li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    itemClick(event) {
      // context.someFunction(); // this doesn't make sense
      this.someFunction(); // call methods.someFunction()
    }, // <--- need use , instead of ; because methods is object, where itemClick() and someFunction() functions will elements of object
    someFunction() {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I change my function to itemClick: function (event) { } and I get context. And I find my function this.someFunction(). Thanks